# Is it possible to use a function to calculate the real tic values based on the auto generated tic values in colorbox

Tags: gnuplot, colorbox, legend

I want to use a function to calculate the real tic value based its automatically generated value.

Here is the example:

```
set pm3d;
set pm3d map;
splot x*y;
```

It gives:

[image]

I want to use a function f(x)=x^2 to calculate the real tic values for the color box based on its automatically generated tic values: 100, 50, 0, -50, -100. Then the displayed values should be 10000, 2500, 0, 2500, 10000.

If it is difficult to deal with repeated 2500 and 10000, a solution to generate only half the legend values: 10000, 2500, 0 would also help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the automatically generated cbtics with `set cbtics add ...`:

```
set pm3d map
f(x) = x**2
set for [i=-100:100:50] cbtics add (sprintf('%d', f(i)) i)
splot x*y
```

[image]

But this solution assumes, that you know the values of the automatic cbtics.

Comment: First time to know for loop can be nested within the set command. Does this work for all commands?

Comment: It works for many (all?) `set` commands, e.g. `set for [i=1:5] linetype i lc rgb sprintf('#%02x0000', 50*i); plot x, 2*x, 3*x, 4*x, 5*x`.